# Integrating DiffEq (and solving for C) yields $C^2=9$ Do you use +3, -3, or both?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

***Disclaimer: I am not a student trying to get free internet homework help. I am an adult who is learning Calculus from a textbook. I am deeply grateful to the members of this community for their time.***

I have a velocity function $v=8\sqrt{s}$ along with an initial condition of $s(0)=9$  (.........That's an "s" in the radical)

I solved this DE below, and got $s=(4t+3)^2$, but am wondering about the part where I solve for the +C (constant of integration).   Specifically, the $c^2=9$.   Why can't C also equal -3 ?  This would result in a different solution $s=(4t-3)^2$  This would have the same derivative as the other solution, and also satisfy the initial condition of  $s(0)=9$  .... Right?  Are there multiple solutions to the problem?

[image]

Comment: So, both solutions are correct?   The proper step is to say that C = +3 and -3 ?

Comment: Well, in this case, with a physical interpretation, there is a problem with $c=-3.$ Indeed, $ds/dt=2(4t+ c)=8\sqrt{s}.$ Since $\sqrt{s}\ge 0$ it should be $4t+ c\ge 0.$ Thus implies that we have to consider $c>0.$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Because $s=(4t+C)^2$ that means position (s) HAS to be positive?  Therefore $\sqrt{s}$ also has to be (+) ?  What is the physical limitation?

Comment: ie:  Just b/c s is (+), why does that mean the square root must be positive?  Is s = 100, $\sqrt{s}$ can still equal -10

Comment: Note that if $c=-3$ then $ds/dt=2(4t-3)<0$ for $t\in (0,3/4).$ Thus, on such interval, $ds/dt<0$ and $\sqrt{s}>0.$

Comment: So, in this one, once I got to y^2 = .... (Bottom left)  
I subbed right there, and got 1 solution. 

But, can't you solve for y = +-sqrt(...) and get 2 solutions?
Is there an accepted method?

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Ods.jpg

Comment: There is no acceptable correct reply, hence no green check.

Comment: Ok have fun figuring things out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest applying the initial condition $s(0)=9$ at the step
$$
s^{1/2}=4t+C.
$$
Then, you have 
$$
\sqrt{9}=4(0)+C\implies C=3.
$$

The upshot of this is you don't have to get an *explicit* solution before you apply the initial condition---you can apply the IC just as well to an *implicit* solution.

Comment: But why should WHEN you apply the init. condition matter?  With your solution, you can get the problem wrong by substitution at the wrong time?  Sounds weird.

Comment: Yes, your second sentence does sound weird... because it is wrong. The solution with $C=-3$ is clearly incorrect as already explained.

Comment: Sorry, but where has anyone explained why C=-3 is incorrect ?